# Error 500 - Get Download drive.files.export

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I am running into an issue with google drive files that are larger than 5 MB (Maybe?) in size. I am trying to download them and export them as `application/pdf` but runs into error 500.

I am using the following code to retrieve and download the drive file (doc, ppt, or xls):

```
- (void)downloadFile:(NSString *)fileID
         completionBlock:(void (^)(NSString *))onCompletionBlock
               failBlock:(void (^)(NSError *))onDownloadFailBlock {

    GTLRQuery *query = [GTLRDriveQuery_FilesExport queryForMediaWithFileId:fileID mimeType:@"application/pdf"];
    GTLRDriveService *service = self.driveService;

    [service executeQuery:query
          completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket *callbackTicket,
                            GTLRDataObject *dataObject,
                            NSError *callbackError) {
            if (callbackError == nil) {
                // The file downloaded successfully; its data is available as dataObject.data
                // File has been downloaded 
            } else {
                if (onDownloadFailBlock) {
                    onDownloadFailBlock(callbackError);
                }
                return;
            }
    }];
}
```

Below is an log that I get using `GTMSessionFetcher`:

```
Download drive.files.export

2017-03-30 22:37:50 +0000  elapsed: 29.406sec
Request: GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[fileID]/export?alt=media&mimeType=application%2Fpdf
Request headers:
  Accept: application/json
  Authorization: Bearer _snip_
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  User-Agent: org.cocoapods.GoogleAPIClientForREST/1.2.1 google-api-objc-client/3.0 iPhone/10.2 hw/sim (gzip)

Response: status 500
Response headers:
  Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
  Content-Encoding: gzip
  Content-Length: 123
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
  Date: Thu, 30 Mar 2017 22:37:50 GMT
  Expires: Thu, 30 Mar 2017 22:37:50 GMT
  Server: GSE
  Vary: Origin, X-Origin
  alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="37,36,35"
  x-content-type-options: nosniff
  x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
  x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block

Response body: (180 bytes)
{
  "error" : {
    "message" : "Internal Error",
    "errors" : [
      {
        "reason" : "internalError",
        "message" : "Internal Error",
        "domain" : "global"
      }
    ],
    "code" : 500
  }
}
```

For what's it worth, it seems to me there is a server limit of 30 seconds when it will throw back this error - 500. For files that are less than 5 MB in size, it is doing it correctly and I am able to get back the pdf file. This is usually done under 30 seconds and also, it means it is not an authentication issue.

I have also tried changing the mimeType to `vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` and I would get a 403 error that says `"message": "This file is too large to be exported."`.

Any idea how to go around this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: `www.googleapis.com` Not Found. Is it just a example or you really used it?

Comment: I removed the file ID because unless you are authorized, you won't be able to access it. The fileID is 1IrCPpb8H6GtfsvtbtqK7q4x8IxX0_C2uQC1xaoVYaH4

Comment: are you able to export this file to pdf using the web app at drive.google.com ?

Comment: Yes that works but it takes more than 30 seconds to do so so they must be doing something else to make it work.

Comment: What kind of file is having the problem (doc, sheet, slides)? How do you know it's 5MB?

Comment: They are slides and I know it is more than 5MB because I have download the file using the web.

Answer (score 0):

500 errors are very often the result of timeouts within the internal Drive infrastructure. That would be compatible with the symptoms you are seeing. So a large file is taking so long to render to .pdf that the infrastructure is timing out.

The standard advice is that 500 errors should be backed off and retried using an exponential backoff algorithm. In your case I suggest start the backoff at 5s and that once you've backed off and retried for a total of 30s, if it still fails you should give up.

Comment: I could do the exponential back off but I don't think that would resolve the issue (Most likely it will always fail). The web version is able to do it. Also, we are not really talking about 100 MB files, the test case is 5.2 MB and it fails.

Comment: I suspect you're right, but backoff and retry is literally the only tool in your box. The thinking is that you might get luck and find that the pdf output of your failed attempt has been cached somewhere in the Drive infrastructure that a subsequent export is much faster. If that doesn't get you out of jail, you're stuck with a Drive bug.